# What software is used to generate the reputation graphs on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

I'm particularly interested in the zooming functionality which is done very well. Were these graphs generated using off the shelf software or were they coded from scratch?

Comment: I put a bounty on this question since there seems to be a different question/answer for every year, and there's no source for the provided answer. I'd personally like an official answer from an SE employee, but that is unlikely; I'd still like a source for the provided answer, and also an answer covering both graphs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the [network profile reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), they use [Highcharts JS v2.2.0](http://www.highcharts.com/), as can be seen in the page source code.

Answer (score 6):

When looking at the page source, it appears that Stack Exchange still uses Highcharts.js for their graphs (as of 26/06/2016).

However, they use different versions. Meta.SE uses `v2.1.9` (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Js/third-party/highcharts.js?v=47c74ab4650f)), whereas the Network Profile uses `v2.2.0` (see [here](http://sstatic.net/stackexchange//js/third-party/highcharts.js)).

This is proven by the source code of the reputation pages (both per-site and network):

[Meta.SE reputation page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/285368/angussidney?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2016-05-31%2009:09:29Z):

`<head>`:

[image: script tag - highcharts.js]

`<body>` (notice all of the highchart classes):

[image: many classes such as highcharts-container and highcharts-grid]

---

[Network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5869449/angussidney?tab=reputation):

[image]